# How can I add a watermark to images at the left, not the right

Tags: php

HELLo,
[i'm using this code](http://bit.ly/flCVq0) and its work very good but it add the logo at the right and iam want in on the left

Comment: Any particular reason why you want the left corner instead of the right corner?  It's pretty common to put the watermark in the bottom right corner...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see these lines:

```
21     // destination x and y
22     $imageWidth-$logoWidth, $imageHeight-$logoHeight,
```

That is probably the right (minus the width of the image) bottom (minus the height) point, from where the watermark is started to write.

Try and replace that with for instance this for left top:

```
21     // destination x and y
22     0 , 0,
```

Or if you want left bottom, try:

```
21     // destination x and y
22     0 , $imageHeight-$logoHeight,
```

Answer (score 1):

In row 22:

```
0, $imageHeight - $logoHeight,
```